# MVC .NET How to test whether a link appears on a page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, razor

I was starting to write unit tests for my razor pages ( [Check out this link](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/06/unit-test-your-mvc-views-using-razor.html) ). I was wondering, if I wanted to test whether a link exists for a particular page, I could parse the html and test whether the route "Admin/Index" appears on the page. But what if I change the controller method from Index to Home - it would break my gui unit tests.

Is there a way to unit test whether a link appears on a page that's not coupled to the controllers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you should try to abstract your unit tests from the concrete action of your controller. If you change from Index to Home - from the human perspective that's OK, but from the unit tests perspective it can be DeleteWholeSite instead of Home. And publishing of this link is very dangerous, but can be done by mistake.
So if you change some links on the page, then you should maintain you unit tests, to be sure that your pages contains links reflecting functionality you want provide to the user.

Comment: true, but say if you have a unit test on your view - does it render "Admin/Index" link - and then you change the controller's method name from Index to Home. Would the test still pass? 

Note, I havent yet thought how I would write the unit test. Would it be - expectLink("Admin/Index") or expectLink(Url.Action("Index", "Admin"). The difference is that the latter one might fail if I change the name of the controller method - which may be the behaviour I want.

Comment: I would suggest to use expectLink(Url.Action("Index", "Admin")) syntax.
What I'm trying to say. If you change something in a behaviour of application, then your unit tests should fail. And you should maintain them to fit your current requirements.
For example you have a class MyClass with method Foo(). You covered it with unit tests and then want to rename Foo() to Bar(). You will not expect that your tests will pass in this case, so why you want to have them passed after Action renaming?

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible to do so if you really want. What I would do is to use a web driver like [watin](http://watin.org/) or [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) to write such tests.

Comment: I currently use watin -> but these are actually system tests, not unit tests. They also take a lot of time to run, so you dont get quick feedback if you have broken something.